# wordpress: new WP_Query and WHERE

Tags: wordpress

why ignore my second WHERE function?

With this function I get all news but with all users.

Why grab and users where id is 1?

> $news = new
>   WP_Query('post_type=news&post_author!=1&orderby=ID&order=ASC');

Thanks ;)

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query). The syntax seems to be

```
$news = new WP_Query('post_type=news&author=-1&orderby=ID&order=ASC');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this no work... I get and now news with all authors.

Comment: @lolaola ah, you need to use `author` instead of `post_author` - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the query using the WordPress [WP_Query API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query).  WordPress handles the WHERE for you when you use the `author`(id) integer or `author_name` (string).

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'ordery' => 'id',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'author' => (-1)
    );

$news = new WP_Query($args);
```